# Cite an example given in package in research project

Tags: citations

I am doing stat research. I really need to give an example of my method. Then, I find a good example in one of R-package (R is a programming language). This example is general for my study and I have already understand it. Do I need to cite it in my research?

Comment: Are you saying that you will copy this example, as written in the package documentation, into your thesis (or whatever you're writing)? Or that you used this example to learn how to use the package, but that's all?

Comment: I update some method (my own method). This method need a specific matrix to use (this matrix is an order of my variables). Then, after I set this matrix, I can update the existing method. However, both of these method are share this matrix. Which is not unique for anyone but it is general. I found one matrix and would like to use it. That is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to use the example, you can always cite the package with `citation("package")` for the specific package, and `citation()` for R.

If your question is rather on *how* to present the original example and your modifications, I believe this should be done in the appendix, with clear annotation of the parts that come from the package and the lines you have modified yourself.